# Clean way to configure cell in mvp architecture

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function for table view cell, but it has a lot of responsibilities:

1. formatting data (I do it with extension for Date)
2. setting texts for labels
3. hide/unhide progress images (called parameteres) depends on number of indexPath row
4. checking if last saved record is from today (if yes, change text labels)

   class TableViewCell below

   ```
     func setProgressParameteres(positive: Bool) {
            if positive {
                arrowProgress.image = UIImage(systemName: Images.arrowUp)
                arrowProgress.tintColor = .green
                weightProgress.textColor = .green
            } else {
                arrowProgress.image = UIImage(systemName: Images.arrowDown)
                arrowProgress.tintColor = .red
                weightProgress.textColor = .red
            }
        }

        func configureCell(tableViewData: [BodyWeightCalendarModel], indexPath: IndexPath) {

            //formatted retrieved date

            let formattedDateWithTime = tableViewData[indexPath.row].date.getFormattedDate(format: DateFormats.formatDayMonthTime)

            let formattedDate = tableViewData[indexPath.row].date.getFormattedDate(format: DateFormats.formatYearMonthDay)

            let weight = String(tableViewData[indexPath.row].weight)

            weightValue.text = "\(weight) \(weightUnit)"

            //Hide progress parameters if first row selected
            if indexPath.row == tableViewData.count - 1 {
                hideProgressParameters(bool: true)
            } else {
                let progressValue = tableViewData[indexPath.row].weight - tableViewData[indexPath.row + 1].weight

                let progressValueString = String(format: "%.1f", progressValue)

                weightProgress.text = ("\(progressValueString) kg")

                //Check if progression is on + or -
                if progressValue > 0 {
                    setProgressParameteres(positive: true)
                } else {
                    setProgressParameteres(positive: false)
                }
                hideProgressParameters(bool: false)
            }

            // Check if last record is from today
            if formattedDate == todayDate {
                dayLabel.text = "Today"
            } else {
                dayLabel.text = formattedDateWithTime


              }
   ```

   }

I wonder what's the best option to make this code cleaner? Create small function and call them all in configureCell or maybe create new TableViewCellPresenter only for this cell and passing this all logic to this presenter?

Comment: You can simply at least one part of the code by telling your date formatter to use relative formatting,  then you will automatically get "today", "yesterday", "Sunday" etc.

Comment: Also, if this code is in your cell, it is in the wrong place. A cell shouldn't know about its row number and you shouldn't need to pass the entire array of table data.  Creating an extension on `Date` to format dates using a DateFormatter seems overly complex too.  It seems you could put a lot of this code in computed properties in a view model object that you pass to the cell

Comment: You can also use Swift's powerful `Measurement` classes for your weights; If you create a weight measurement then it can be automatically formatted in a locale sensitive way (kg in Metric locales, lbs in imperial locales)

Comment: Questions about code that is working but you are seeking to improve can be asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer, but I have one question to you. You said "you don't need to pass entire array of table data" and "cell shouldn't know about its row number". But I need entire array of table data and rows to calculate difference between previous and next record in db (weight progression from training to training) so in this case passing entire data and knowledge about rows is also bad?

Comment: Yes. A cell is a view. Your view controller or view model should pass it the data it needs.  It shouldn't contain any computational logic.  Of course, *it can*, as you have done. It is just a question of style. Personally, I wouldn't couple the cell and the model data in this way.

Comment: Ok so If I have Model View Presenter architecture, can I use same presenter for table view controller class and for table view cell class or create seperated presenter for table view cell class?

Comment: Your `UIViewController` would be your presenter in this case.  You would have all of this code in your `cellForRowAt` and in that method you would set the various views of your tableview cell directly